# need to test functionality with oracle stored proc

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

i have code like this:

```
protected function _checkUserVisibility()
{
    try {
        if (!$params->getUsrParametr(self::ACTIVE_FIF)) { // calling oracle stored proc
            throw new Unitex_Exception('ALARM');
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->logOut();
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

this func caled from another one (and so on).

a a question:
how to get worked unit test for that parts of code?

**EDIT1:**

firstly taked hehe http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.test.phpunit.html
than improoved (hope)
test proc is:

```
class UserControllerTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase {
..........
public function testLoginAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $request->setMethod('POST')
        ->setHeader('X_REQUESTED_WITH', 'XMLHttpRequest')
        ->setPost(array(
                'user'     => 'test_user',
                'password' => 'test_pwd',
        ));

        $filialId = 1;
        $stmt1 = Zend_Test_DbStatement::createUpdateStatement();
        $this->getAdapter()->appendStatementToStack($stmt1);
        $this->getAdapter()->appendStatementToStack($stmt1);
        $this->getAdapter()->appendStatementToStack($stmt1);
        $this->getAdapter()->appendStatementToStack($stmt1);

        $stmt1Rows = array(array('IRL_ALIAS' => 'RO_COMMON', 'ISADM' => 'N'));
        $stmt1 = Zend_Test_DbStatement::createSelectStatement($stmt1Rows);
        $this->getAdapter()->appendStatementToStack($stmt1);

        $this->dispatch('/user/login');// <-- crash here
    $this->assertController('user');
    $this->assertAction('login');
    $this->assertNotRedirect();
    $this->_getResponseJson();
}
```

Comment: FYI, what you're looking for is PHPUnit to test the PHP.  Oracle DB doesn't really have anything to do with how you would unit test this PHP code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your unit test definitly you don't want any database interaction. The answer for your question is use stub for db functionality.

Let say that $`params` is property of `SomeClass` contains `getUsrParametr` which for example gets something from database. You're testing `_checkUserVisibility` method so you don't care about what are happening in `SomeClass`. That's way you test will look something like that:

```
class YourClass
{
    protected $params;

    public function __construct(SomeClass $params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        $this->_checkUserVisibility();
    }

    protected function _checkUserVisibility()
    {
        try {
            if (!$this->params->getUsrParametr(self::ACTIVE_FIF)) { // calling oracle stored proc
                throw new Unitex_Exception('ALARM');
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->logOut();
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

And the unit test of course the only method you test is the public one, but you cover protected method through testing public one.

```
public function testDoSomethingAlarm()
{
    // set expected exception:
    $this->setExpectedException('Unitex_Exception', 'ALARM');

    // create the stub
    $params = $this->getMock('SomeClass', array('getUsrParametr'));

    // and set desired result
    $params->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getUsrParametr')
        ->will($this->returnValue(false));

    $yourClass = new YourClass($params);
    $yourClass->doSomething();
}
```

And the second test which test case if `getUsrParametr` will returns `true`:

```
public function testDoSomethingLogout()
{
    // set expected exception:
    $this->setExpectedException('SomeOtherException');

    // create the stub
    $params = $this->getMock('SomeClass', array('getUsrParametr'));

    // set throw desired exception to test logout
    $params->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getUsrParametr')
        ->will($this->throwException('SomeOtherException'));

    // now you want create mock instead of real object beacuse you want check if your class will call logout method:   
    $yourClass = $this->getMockBuilder('YourClass')
        ->setMethods(array('logOut'))
        ->setConstructorArgs(array($params))
        ->getMock();

    // now you want ensure that logOut will be called
    $yourClass->expects($this->once())
        ->method('logOut');

    // pay attention that you've mocked only logOut method, so doSomething is real one
    $yourClass->doSomething();
}
```

Comment: your answer looks good, but do not understand where and how. i added edit1. could you please help?

Comment: "where and how" what? :) I'm not sure if completely understand you. But according to my understanding: the problem happens because inside "dispatch" method you doing something with database and then it crashes. If so, then you just need mock your "dispatch" method (you can base on examples from my answer) and that will be fine

Comment: think u r Zend programmer =).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PHP 5.3.2+ with PHPUnit, you can test your private and protected methods by using reflection to set them to be public prior to running your tests, otherwise you test protected/private methods by properly testing the public methods that use the protected/private methods.  Generally speaking the later of the two options is generally how you should do it, but if you want to use reflection, here's a generic example:

```
protected static function getMethod($name) {
  $class = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');
  $method = $class->getMethod($name);
  $method->setAccessible(true);
  return $method;
}

public function testFoo() {
  $foo = self::getMethod('foo');
  $obj = new MyClass();
  $foo->invokeArgs($obj, array(...));
  ...
}
```

Comment: problem not in testing private func. problem in testing puboic func that calling private func that containing calling storet proc and awaiting result in storedproc params. but if no calling stored proc - no parans and therefore - one way - exception